# Handling Android Runtime permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

What is the best Android library available to make handling runtime permissions for Android Marshmallow, while ensuring backward compatibility so that the application doesn't break on a device running Android IceCreamSandwich or Gingerbread?

Comment: You can check a class that I've created and use it in Fragments https://github.com/mptrista/PermissionHelper
It is for fragments and in the case for requesting a single permission.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [PermissionUtil](https://github.com/kayvannj/PermissionUtil) library makes life very easy. Here is how you can ask for permission and act on user's response:

```
mRequestObject = PermissionUtil.with(this).request(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).onAllGranted(
                new Func() {
                    @Override protected void call() {
                        //Happy Path
                    }
                }).onAnyDenied(
                new Func() {
                    @Override protected void call() {
                        //Sad Path
                    }
                }).ask(REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE);
```

and calling this method on your activity's `onRequestPermissionsResult`:

```
mRequestObject.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
```

Don't forget to add the permission to manifest.